# An alternative to utf8 and arabtex under memoir documentclass

Tags: memoir, unicode, font-encodings, arabic

I'd like to use `utf8` and `arabtex` packages under the `memoir` `documentclass`, but it seems unlikely to happen ([previous discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42254/switching-an-existing-document-to-memoir-how-much-trouble-is-it)). What would be a good alternative, no transliteration and something that works with T1 encoding?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}


\begin{document}

بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم

\end{document}
```

This will produce an error:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex\latex\arabtex\arabtex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex\latex\arabtex\aconfig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex\latex\arabtex\arabaux.sty")

! Class memoir Error: Font command \it is not supported.

See the memoir class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.551 \settransfont {\rm \it }
                              % standard font for transliteration
```

Comment: Would you please show a minimal example of a document using `arabtex` that cannot be converted to `memoir`?

Comment: @egreg  MWE done.

Comment: This doesn't produce Arabic output.

Comment: @AymanElmasry Arabtex is meant to be **transliterated**. I you don't want transliteration maybe you better check out XeTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Yes, so it seems. I'm not sure about switching to XeLaTeX, I've been switching to a lot of things lately, I suppose I'll take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get back the functionality of the "old" font commands by writing, after `\documentclass[<options>]{memoir}`,

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\makeatother
```

However, as remarked by Yiannis,

```
\documentclass[<options>,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
```

does this without extra code. Here `<options>` stands for all the other options you want to pass to `memoir`, in your case call it as

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
```

Comment: The option `oldfontcommands` incorporates old font commands in the memoir class.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Great, Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind switching to another engine, the following should work with XeTeX (xelatex) and you get access to any Arabic OpenType font:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri} % or any other font


\begin{document}

\textarabic{بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم}

\begin{Arabic}
بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Khaled’s answer works fine for many things, but for me there’s always a conflict with one or more packages when I write Arabic. The solution I found in one TexShop template, if I don’t want to type the whole text in Arabic, is:

```
\newfontfamily{\A}{Geeza Pro} %or any other font
{\A بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم}
```