# Count references and link pages

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, counters

I'd like to know how to count the number of times that I cited some reference and to mark the pages that I make the reference. Below you will find an exemple, where "Citado 3 vezes nas páginas vii, 28 e 29" means "Cited 3 times at the pages vii, 28 and 29". Whatever the solution, it should be possible to put the words in portuguese. Of course, the pages marked must be hyperref-connected. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: [How to show Not cited and Cited i times on pages …, in the bibliography when using biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390536/how-to-show-not-cited-and-cited-i-times-on-pages-in-the-bibliography-when-u/390571#390571)

Comment: @Jojo They used biblatex package. Is not possible to use natbib?